# How to pass a function result to a tuple?

Tags: python, django, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I am working on a Python/Django/Wagtail project, and at some point I have a class  like this:

```
class SuperClass(BaseClass):

    body = StreamField([
        ('overview_speakers', OverviewSpeakers()),
    ])

    def some_function():
        return 'Hola'
```

**OverviewSpeakers** is a class that is expecting an argument and I want to try to pass in the results of **some_function()**

I tried both:

```
body = StreamField([
    ('overview_speakers', OverviewSpeakers(self.some_function())),
])
```

and

```
body = StreamField([
    ('overview_speakers', OverviewSpeakers(SuperClass.some_function())),
])
```

But respectively it yells that ***self*** or ***SuperClass*** are not defined.

What can I do to pass in the results of the function?

Comment: You must define the function before using it. Put the definition of `some_function` before the initialization of `body`.

Comment: @DYZ And how do I call the function?

Comment: didn't work with 'self', still says `self is not defined`

Comment: however it seems it worked calling it directly as some_function()

Comment: Just as you would call any other function: `some_function()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

```
class SuperClass(BaseClass):

    def some_function():
        return 'Hola'

    body = StreamField([
        ('overview_speakers', OverviewSpeakers(some_function())),
    ])
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot refer to a class that is being defined, but you can add attibutes to it after it is defined. So this should work:

```
class SuperClass(BaseClass):
    def some_function():
        return 'Hola'

SuperClass.body = StreamField([
    ('overview_speakers', OverviewSpeakers(SuperClass.some_function())),
])
```